# dynamic table creation background color

Tags: php

I am creating a table full of values dynamically... I was woundering if there is a way to alternate the row color of this table between white and light grey..

this is the code I am using to create the table...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['width'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" name="duckdown_id" value="'.$row['duckdown_id'].'" /><input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Delete" /></form></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What would you do if you were human to do this? What have you tried?

Comment: Your code looks pretty out dated + why do you use a form to submit only one value?

Comment: @HurkNburkS : Don't forget to select an answer when you settle on an acceptable solution to your problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an incremental variable and check every 2'nd row:

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $background = '#000';
  if($i%2 == 0){
      $background = '#00f';
  }
  $i++;
  echo "<tr style='background-color:".$background.";'>";
```

As a side note, I see you are still using `mysql_*` functions, If you just started you could move to `PDO` as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. [Here is a nice tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: oh awesome! going to try it out now!!! I should have thought of this.. finding it hard to get my head round php.. im used to being able to debug code and getting direct results.. if you know what i mean..

Comment: That's the approach I'd take...  better yet, I would set a class instead of a style attribute.

Answer (score 3):

My approach, very similar to (and based off of) @Mihai Iorga's would be css class-based:

CSS:

```
gray { background-color: gray; }
red { background-color: red; }
```

PHP:

```php
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $background = 'gray';
  if($i%2) {
      $background = 'red';
  }
  $i++;
  echo "<tr class='$background'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use CSS (with code from Mihai lorga)

PHP

```
$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($i%2 == 0){
        echo "<tr class=even>";
    }else{
        echo "<tr class=odd>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    //etc.
    $i++;
}
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .even{
        background-color:#00f;
    }
    .odd{
        background-color:#000;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: ahh stupid me. Im currently working on some javascript myself ;) so i mixed it up. Changed it Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple jquery code as below,

```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
      $('tbody tr:odd').addClass("row-odd");
      $('tbody tr:even').addClass("row-even");  
   });
```

And define 'row-odd' and 'row-even' classes in your style sheet.